# My Datatable not working correctly inside my laravel view

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I am using jquery data table in my laravel app to get the data from controller inside my table in view

And my view is

```
 <table class="table table-bordered data-table" id="products_sold">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Product Name</th>
                        <th>Seller Name</th>
                        <th>Brand</th> 
                        <th>Product Price</th>
                        <th>Shipping Price</th>
                    </tr>
              </thead>
          </table>
```

My jquery function is

```
$('#products_sold').DataTable({
     "processing": true,
     "serverSide":true,
        "ajax": "{{ route('user.sold_products') }}",
        "columns": [
            { data: 'name', name: 'name' },
            { data: 'seller_id', name: 'seller_id'},
            { data: 'brand', name: 'brand' },
            { data: 'price_per_unit', name: 'price_per_unit'},
            { data: 'selling_fee', name: 'selling_fee' },
        ]
    });
```

This is inside my controller function

```
 public function sold_products(){
        $uid = Auth::user()->id;
        $product = Product::where('buyer_id','!=',0)->where('seller_id',$uid)->get();
        return Response::json([
            'data' => $product
        ], 200);
    }
```

I doknow what is missed out can anyone please help me to display my data inside table

Comment: did you getting any error ?

Comment: No JYOTHI ...I didnot get any error

Comment: may be it will help try it https://datatables.yajrabox.com/starter

Comment: Shouldn't `"ajax": "{{ route('user.sold_products') }}",` to be a url?

Comment: yeah i giving the route name  `Route::get('sold-products', 'User\DashboardController@sold_products')->name('user.sold_products');` like this